# Поразрядное исключающее ИЛИ

Tags: java

Возникла проблема с этой операцией.

0011
^0110

---

0001

а, как я понимаю должно быть 0101 ,так как если только один операнд равен = 1 то и результат ровен 1
Объясните пожалуйста

Comment: Вроде должно 101 получиться, т.е. 5. Только исключающее или (сложение по модулю 2) - это крышечка, т.е. ^.

Answer (score 1):

Покажите как вы используете это в коде, запись верная, возможно ошибка в другом месте.
Мой пример:

```
int a = 3;
int b = 6;
int c = a ^ b;
```

c==5